# Value changed after Azure ML Studio Web Service

Tags: c#, web-services, azure-machine-learning-service

I am using Azure ML Studio in order to predict some values. I have noticed that one of my value was changed when I receive the result from the Web Service. Indeed, I have the following array **[27,7,2018,11,2,4,1]** which become **[27,7,2018,11,2,4,0]**. It is the first time I notice a such comportment. I did not see other value changed in my csv. It occurs all the time with my actual input. I do not know where to start to find the source of the issue.

I tried to read the response that way :

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("", scoreRequest);
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

And that way :

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("", scoreRequest);

if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    var tmp3 = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
    var tmp4 = ReadFully(tmp3);
    var tmp5 = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(tmp4);
}

public static byte[] ReadFully(Stream input)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            int read;
            while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

This is the shape of my model on Azure ML (In the top left, top right and bottom python scripts random forest is applied) :
[image]

Comment: What does your model look like?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are doing two-class predications,and the 1,0 should be the result of "Scored Labels"